# Binary Search Algorithm Difference

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-search

As far as I test, there is no any bug point tested. However, I wonder that if there is a problem with the usage of `arr.Length` or `arr.Length - 1`.
Further, as to the boundaries like begin <= end with end = mid - 1 or begin < end with end = mid as in the codes.

// size is array length

```
private static int BinarySearch(int[] arr, int element)
{
    int begin = 0;
    int end = arr.Length;

    for (; begin < end ;)
    {
        int mid = begin + (( - begin + end) / 2);
        if (arr[mid] == element) return mid;
        if (arr[mid] > element)
        {
            // in left
            end = mid;
        }
        else
        {
            begin = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

// size is array length - 1

```
private static int BinarySearch(int[] arr, int element)
{
    int begin = 0;
    int end = arr.Length - 1;

    for (; begin < end ;)
    {
        int mid = begin + (( - begin + end) / 2);
        if (arr[mid] == element) return mid;
        if (arr[mid] > element)
        {
            // in left
            end = mid;
        }
        else
        {
            begin = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @BCdotWEB is it matter? It is just an algorithm.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I changed the tag from java to C# based on the `Length` property. In java it would be `length`.

Comment: @snr it matters because we review the code. We maybe comment on namings which are part of a naming-guideline which are different for different languages.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I test, there is no any bug point tested.

Well, then you didn't test all of the edge cases, did you?

Given the array `int[] arr = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` I would at least test for the following edge-cases:

- first item -> `0 == BinarySearch(arr, 1);`
- middle item -> `2 == BinarySearch(arr, 3);`
- last item ->  `4 == BinarySearch(arr, 5);`
- non existing positive-item -> `-1 == BinarySearch(arr, 6);`
- always check for zero -> `-1 == BinarySearch(arr, 0);`
- non existing negativ-item  -> `-1 == BinarySearch(arr, -1);`

That beeing said, the second version fails on the last-item-check.

Comment: Thank you sir. Any idea as to the boundaries like begin <= end with end = mid - 1 or begin < end with end = mid as in the codes?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to elaborate on some of the comments regarding tagging with post with the correct language.  As @Heslacher states, each language has its own standards and conventions.

In C#, method naming suggests that `BinarySearch` is a poor name for your method.  A more suitable name would be `FindIndex` or `FindIndexUsingBinarySearch`.  The latter is definitely wordier but leaves little doubt as to what the method does.

The comment `// in left` is not needed as it tells a developer nothing that he or she doesn't already know.

A binary search requires a sorted array, or more precisely to your method, an array sorted in ascending order.  With C#, the abbreviated parameter name of `arr` is frowned upon.  Instead, it should be `array` or perhaps even `sortedArray`.

Turning to your 2 methods and the use of `begin`, `end`, and `mid`.  In both methods, `begin` and `mid` are inclusive indices to the sorted array, **but `end` is an exclusive index in the first version but an inclusive index in the second**.  Understanding this provides insights on how to correct the second version.

This original line:

```
int mid = begin + (( - begin + end) / 2);
```

For the first method should be:

```
int mid = begin + ((end - begin) / 2);
```

And for the second method, where `end` is inclusive, should be:

```
int mid = begin + ((end - begin + 1) / 2);
```

In the second method, you would also need to adjust:

```
end = mid;
```

with

```
end = mid - 1;
```